# how to implement a global state with guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I want to create a global state (data object, not a service object).

I have created class `MyDataObject`.

I want to avoid regular global state,

but prefer using `Guice` dependency injection.

However all the tutorials show how to set a DI for service object with registration to interface.

How can I use `Guice` injection for my need?

**Edit**

I have tried:

public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(E2eResult.class).toInstance(new E2eResult());
}
```

}

with:

```
    @Test
    public void sendSearchRequest() throws Exception {

...
e2eResult = injector.getInstance(E2eResult.class);

        timerUtils.setTimeOut(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli);
        timerUtils.startStopWatch();

...

        long timeElapsed = timerUtils.stopStopWatch();
        e2eResult.runTime = timeElapsed;


...
    }
```

and:

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());
        Result result = runTest(classAndMethod);
        E2eResult e2eResult = injector.getInstance(E2eResult.class);
}
```

and yet I saw the  in the `main` was without the new long value.

Comment: I don't think I really understand your question... Do guice's [instance binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings) or [singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) can help you ?

Comment: No, because it deals with binding concrete classes to interface. here :`@Singleton
public class InMemoryTransactionLog implements TransactionLog {`   my dataObject implements no interface.

Comment: Not necessarily, see my answer

Comment: Is the test using the same injector as `main()`?

Comment: I wish I knew how to make them use the same one. how would you write this?

Answer (score 4):

To inject GlobalState class you should first a create an instance of it(set it as you like) and then bind class to instance:

```
bind(GlobalState.class)
    .toInstance(globalState);
```

GlobalState can be created and configured in your "module", you can read about it more here:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: and where do i initiate `globalState` though?

Comment: Test and main are two different processes. Also, it's not good to share state from test to app. Why do you need?

Comment: I want to measure the time run of 2 steps in the test

Answer (score 1):

So you have a plain old java object `GlobalState`:

```
public class GlobalState {
    // whatever...
}
```

You can use the singleton mechanism provided by guice:

```
bind(GlobalState.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Or use the instance binding:

```
bind(GlobalState.class).toInstance(new GlobalState());
```

In this way, you will be able to inject an unique instance of `GlobalState` in your application.

Comment: I tried but `new GlobalState()` in `bind(GlobalState.class).toInstance(new GlobalState());` created a new instance every time. No?

Comment: @user1065869 I don't think so, the guice's wiki says: "You can bind a type to a specific instance of that type" and "Avoid using .toInstance with objects that are complicated to create, since it can slow down application startup". So I suppose it will bind an unique instance to `GlobalState.class`.

Comment: @user1065869 Well, you make me doubt... I need to do some test =D ! Did you try with a singleton ?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually create an "old" bad singleton

No need for special binding

because i didn't have any pre-loaded object.

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
}
```

just to carry a one and only guice injector

```
public class InjectorSingleton {

    public Injector guiceInjector;
    private static InjectorSingleton singleton;

    private InjectorSingleton() {
        guiceInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());
    }

    public static InjectorSingleton getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new InjectorSingleton();
        }

        return singleton;
    }

}
```

and I call this from my `main class` and from my `test class`

`InjectorSingleton.getInstance().guiceInjector.getInstance(MyDataObject.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Fashionably late to the party. I just wanted to share this pattern.

```
package modules;

public class MetricsModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // The initializer is an eager singleton
    bind(modules.MetricsModule.MeterRegistryInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }

  private static class MeterRegistryInitializer {

    @Inject
    // When initialized, Guice will handle the injection as usual
    public MeterRegistryInitializer(Config config, MeterRegistry registry) {
      var instance = config.getString("instance.id");

      registry.config().commonTags(List.of(
          Tag.of("instance", instance)
      ));

      // This is global state
      Metrics.addRegistry(registry);
    }
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  MeterRegistry provideMeterRegistry(
      @MetricsDriver String driver,
      PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusRegistry
  ) {
    MeterRegistry registry;

    switch (driver) {
      case "none":
        registry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
        break;
      case "prometheus":
        registry = prometheusRegistry;
        break;
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    return registry;
  }
}
```